How to "reset" PyCharm run window to have both debugger and output load into the same window?
Previously, whenever I used PyCharm, my debug window and my output window would load in the same window, instead of them loading in separate windows (see the screenshot below). I also have to constantly click View > Tool Windows > Run every time I launch PyCharm to get the output box to show now.
PyCharm version: 2023.3.3
Operating System: Windows
I'm not sure what I may have done, I've tried messing around with toggling different view settings on and off to try and fix the behavior, but I'm still stuck.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
